# Is there any way to replay a cutscene?

Tags: uncharted-3

In *Uncharted 3: Drake's Deception*, I missed a few cutscenes for various reasons and feel like I've missed a few key plot points. Since there's no shortage of cutscenes, I'm hoping there is some method of watching them again. Is there any method to replay a cutscene without reloading from a save and playing through again?

Comment: I know it's not a really a solution, but YouTube helps :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbdmTTx5FGc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Patch 1.02 (released November 27, 2011) adds a cutscene viewer.

http://www.naughtydog.com/site/post/uncharted_3_patch_102_notes

Answer (score 5):

In game. No.

After playing through and defeating the game, I was hopeful it would be some sort of unlock or bonus content. It is not. There are no options to replay cutscenes within the game or the game menus.

As mentioned by @JohnoBoy, you can find them on YouTube if you're willing to dig through and find the pieces you want to watch.

This playlist has 4 parts (over 1 hour), and is not complete, but hopefully will be completed.

Comment: This is a bad change from the older games. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you must restart the level to see the scenes missed.